# How to add active class only for exact routes and not parent routes in ember js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have two routes which are nested like this.

**router.js**

```
this.route('profile', function() {
  this.route('edit');
});
```

and couple of navbar links for these routes like this..

**navbar.hbs**

```
{{#link-to 'profile' tagName="li"}}<a href>View Profile</a>{{/link-to}}
{{#link-to 'profile.edit' tagName="li"}}<a href>Edit Profile</a>{{/link-to}}
```

The `link-to` helper adds `active` class to the `li` tag here. So when I am in `profile` route, the first link has `active` class and when I am in `profile.edit` route, both the links have `active` class. (apparently because both the routes get activated when `profile.edit` is visited.)

How can I avoid the parent route link to get the `active` class when in a child route?

Basically I don't want the first link (to `profile`) to have `active` class when in `profile.edit` route.

Comment: You can use `current-when`, though I think that will mask the fact that the routes probably shouldn't be nested in that case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured it out if anyone else is facing same issue.

I just changed the link to `profile` and made it to explicitly `profile.index`.

**navbar.hbs**

```
{{#link-to 'profile.index' tagName="li"}}<a href>View Profile</a>{{/link-to}}
{{#link-to 'profile.edit' tagName="li"}}<a href>Edit Profile</a>{{/link-to}}
```

This way, When in `profile.edit` route, the first link does not get the `active` class.